# How to Write JavaScript Object like that

Tags: javascript, oop

**How to write an Object for using this object like below**

```
var cal = new calculator;

cal.add(10).add(20).miniz(2).div(2);

console.log(cal.result()); // result 14
```

Comment: `return this;` will be useful in your construction.

Comment: a constructor would be useful.

Comment: how exactly?? @NinaScholz

Comment: This isn't a *how-to* tutorial service. Question is too broad

Comment: You really ought to show us you can create the basics of an object with methods.  Then object chaining is simply done by adding a `return this` to every method that you want to be chainable and storing intermediate results in the object's instance data.   We don't just write code for you here.  We help you solve problems in code you've already tried to write.

Comment: [Fluent Interfaces - Method Chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293353/fluent-interfaces-method-chaining) offers some general advice, ableit with snippets in C#, and Wikipedia's [Fluent Interface: JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript) provides an example for JS.

Comment: may be please take a look in javascript prototyping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, this is one way to do it:

[My Example](https://jsbin.com/ravenat/1/edit?js,console)

```
var calculator = function() {
  this.curr = 0;
  this.add = function(n) {
    this.curr += n;
    return this; // returning this at the end of each method is the key to chaining
  };
  this.miniz = function(n) {
    this.curr -= n;
    return this;
  };
  this.div = function(n) {
    this.curr = this.curr / n;
    return this;
  };
  this.result = function() {
    return this.curr;
  };
};
```

You need to change the instantiation to this:

```
var cal = new calculator();
```

Comment: You could use `prototype` to define the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started:

```js
function Calculator() {
    var value = 0;
    this.add = function (v) {
        value += v;
        return this;
    };
    this.result = function () {
        return value;
    };
}

var cal = new Calculator;

console.log(cal.add(10).result()); // result 10
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this is will help some what..

```
var Calc = function(){
   this.value = 0;  
};

Calc.prototype.add = function(val){
    this.value += val;
    return this;
};
```

then you can use like `new Calc().add(100).add(100)`

but before make sure understood how prototyping is working,

for ref : [a sample](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculator(){
    this.val = 0;
    this.add = function(num){
        this.val += num;
        return this;
    };

    this.miniz = function(num){
        this.val -= num;
        return this;
    };

    this.div = function(num){
        this.val /= num;
        return this;  
    };

    this.result = function(){
        return this.val;
    };
}
```