# Creating API that is fluent

Tags: c#, fluent

How does one go about create an API that is fluent in nature?

Is this using extension methods primarily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for writing fluent interfaces in C# 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224730/tips-for-writing-fluent-interfaces-in-c-sharp-3)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160809050251/http://rrpblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=33) explains it much better than I ever could.

EDIT, can't squeeze this in a comment...

There are two sides to interfaces, the implementation and the usage.  There's more work to be done on the creation side, I agree with that, however the main benefits can be found on the usage side of things.  Indeed, for me the main advantage of fluent interfaces is a more natural, easier to remember and use and why not, more aesthetically pleasing API.  And just maybe, the effort of having to squeeze an API in a fluent form may lead to better thought out API?

As Martin Fowler says in [the original article about fluent interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html):

> Probably the most important thing to
> notice about this style is that the
> intent is to do something along the
> lines of an internal
> DomainSpecificLanguage. Indeed this is
> why we chose the term 'fluent' to
> describe it, in many ways the two
> terms are synonyms. The API is
> primarily designed to be readable and
> to flow. The price of this fluency is
> more effort, both in thinking and in
> the API construction itself. The
> simple API of constructor, setter, and
> addition methods is much easier to
> write. Coming up with a nice fluent
> API requires a good bit of thought.

As in most cases API's are created once and used over and over again, the extra effort may be worth it.

And verbose?  I'm all for verbosity if it serves the readability of a program.

Comment: I don't really understand how this makes for a fluent API, and actually think this design pattern is very verbose.

Comment: ok... so it matches the wikipedia definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface  I still think it's horrible to implement.

Comment: Verbose doesn't serve the readability of the program in this case, it serves the readability of the client application.  Your API still needs to be improved and maintained.

Comment: Although I do agree, more thought put into an API design can't be a bad thing.

Comment: Do you use LINQ? if so, that's an excellent example of a fluent API. Have fun without it!

Comment: The first link seems to be broken.

Comment: Tthe first link to the Randy Peterson Azure blog is stale; it's archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20160809050251/http://rrpblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=33

Answer (score 38):

MrBlah,

Though you can write extension methods to write a fluent interface, a better approach is using the builder pattern. I'm in the same boat as you and I'm trying to figure out a few advanced features of fluent interfaces.

Below you'll see some sample code that I created in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794848/writing-my-first-dsl-in-c-and-getting-hung-up-on-funct-action)

```
public class Coffee
{
    private bool _cream;
    private int _ounces;

    public static Coffee Make { get { return new Coffee(); } }

    public Coffee WithCream()
    {
        _cream = true;
        return this;
    }
    public Coffee WithOuncesToServe(int ounces)
    {
        _ounces = ounces;
        return this;
    }
}

var myMorningCoffee = Coffee.Make.WithCream().WithOuncesToServe(16);
```

Comment: Like it, very clear example although where is the interface definition? :)

Comment: Using C# object initializer syntax instead your example would be more succinct (and avoid needing to write `WithFoo` methods), and make it clear that only properties are being set. I think the "fluent" style should only be used if you need side-effects.

Answer (score 22):

While many people cite Martin Fowler as being a prominent exponent in the fluent API discussion, his early design claims actually evolve around a [fluent builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) or [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Fluent APIs can be further evolved into actual [internal domain-specific languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). An article that explains how a BNF notation of a grammar can be manually transformed into a "fluent API" can be seen here:

http://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course/

It transforms this grammar:

[image]

Into this Java API:

```
// Initial interface, entry point of the DSL
interface Start {
  End singleWord();
  End parameterisedWord(String parameter);
  Intermediate1 word1();
  Intermediate2 word2();
  Intermediate3 word3();
}

// Terminating interface, might also contain methods like execute();
interface End {
  void end();
}

// Intermediate DSL "step" extending the interface that is returned
// by optionalWord(), to make that method "optional"
interface Intermediate1 extends End {
  End optionalWord();
}

// Intermediate DSL "step" providing several choices (similar to Start)
interface Intermediate2 {
  End wordChoiceA();
  End wordChoiceB();
}

// Intermediate interface returning itself on word3(), in order to allow
// for repetitions. Repetitions can be ended any time because this 
// interface extends End
interface Intermediate3 extends End {
  Intermediate3 word3();
}
```

Java and C# being somewhat similar, the example certainly translates to your use-case as well. The above technique has been heavily used in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), a fluent API / internal domain-specific language modelling the SQL language in Java

Answer (score 10):

This is a very old question, and this answer should probably be a comment rather than an answer, but I think it's a topic worth continuing to talk about, and this response is too long to be a comment.

The original thinking concerning "fluency" seems to have been basically about adding power and flexibility (method chaining, etc) to objects while making code a bit more self-explanatory.

For example

```
Company a = new Company("Calamaz Holding Corp");
Person p = new Person("Clapper", 113, 24, "Frank");
Company c = new Company(a, 'Floridex', p, 1973);
```

is less "fluent" than

```
Company c = new Company().Set
    .Name("Floridex");
    .Manager(
        new Person().Set.FirstName("Frank").LastName("Clapper").Awards(24)
    )
    .YearFounded(1973)
    .ParentCompany(
        new Company().Set.Name("Calamaz Holding Corp")
    )
;
```

But to me, the later is not really any more powerful or flexible or self-explanatory than

```
Company c = new Company(){
   Name = "Floridex",
   Manager = new Person(){ FirstName="Frank", LastName="Clapper", Awards=24 },
   YearFounded = 1973,
   ParentCompany = new Company(){ Name="Calamaz Holding Corp." }
};
```

..in fact I would call this last version easier to create, read and maintain than the previous, and I would say that it requires significantly less baggage behind the scenes, as well.  Which to me is important, for (at least) two reasons:

1 - The cost associated with creating and maintaining layers of objects (no matter who does it) is just as real, relevant and important as the cost associated with creating and maintaining the code that consumes them.

2 - Code bloat embedded in layers of objects creates just as many (if not more) problems as code bloat in the code that consumes those objects.

Using the last version means you can add a (potentially useful) property to the Company class simply by adding one, very simple line of code.

That's not to say that I feel there's no place for method chaining. I really like being able to do things like (in JavaScript)

```
var _this = this;
Ajax.Call({
    url: '/service/getproduct',
    parameters: {productId: productId},
)
.Done(
    function(product){
        _this.showProduct(product);
    }
)
.Fail(
    function(error){
        _this.presentError(error);
    }
);
```

..where (in the hypothetical case I'm imagining) Done and Fail were additions to the original Ajax object, and were able to be added without changing any of the original Ajax object code or any of the existing code that made use of the original Ajax object, and without creating one-off things that were exceptions to the general organization of the code.

So I have definitely found value in making a subset of an object's functions return the 'this' object.  In fact whenever I have a function that would otherwise return void, I consider having it return this.

But I haven't yet really found significant value in adding "fluent interfaces" (.eg "Set") to an object, although theoretically it seems like there could be a sort of namespace-like code organization that could arise out of the practice of doing that, which might be worthwhile. ("Set" might not be particularly valuable, but "Command", "Query" and "Transfer" might, if it helped organize things and facilitate and minimize the impact of additions and changes.)  One of the potential benefits of such a practice, depending on how it was done, might be improvement in a coder's typical level of care and attention to protection levels - the lack of which has certainly caused great volumes grief.

Answer (score 6):

KISS: Keep it simple stupid.

Fluent design is about one aesthetic design principle used throughout the API. Thou your methodology you use in your API can change slightly, but it is generally better to stay consistent.

Even though you may think 'everyone can use this API, because it uses all different types of methodology's'. The truth is the user would start feeling lost because your consistently changing the structure/data structure of the API to a new design principle or naming convention.

If you wish to change halfway through to a different design principle eg.. Converting from error codes to exception handling because some higher commanding power. It would be folly and would normally in tail lots of pain. It is better to stay the course and add functionality that your customers can use and sell than to get them to re-write and re-discover all their problems again.

Following from the above, you can see that there is more at work of writing a Fluent API than meet's the eye. There are psychological, and aesthetic choices to make before beginning to write one and even then the feeling,need, and desire to conform to customers demand's and stay consistent is the hardest of all.

Answer (score 5):

**What is a fluent API**

Wikipedia defines them here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

**Why Not to use a fluent interface**

I would suggest not implementing a traditional fluent interface, as it increases the amount of code you need to write, complicates your code and is just adding unnecessary boilerplate.

**Another option, do nothing!**

Don't implement anything.  Don't provide "easy" constructors for setting properties and don't provide a clever interface to help your client.  Allow the client to set the properties however they normally would.  In .Net C# or VB this could be as simple as using [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx).

```
Car myCar = new Car { Name = "Chevrolet Corvette", Color = Color.Yellow };
```

So you don't need to create any clever interface in your code, and this is very readable.

If you have very complex *Sets* of properties which must be set, or set in a certain order, then use a separate configuration object and pass it to the class via a separate property.

```
CarConfig conf = new CarConfig { Color = Color.Yellow, Fabric = Fabric.Leather };
Car myCar = new Car { Config = conf };
```

Comment: The upsides of a fluent API (better readability and a much more intuitive way to work with your API) are much more important than to have a little bit more complicated code. IF you create an API, then it's all about the user that will access your API. If you can please him with a fluent style, I would take all the effort to make working with the API as easy as possible, even if that would mean putting a lot of more work into the API.

Comment: It creates a different interface than everyone else's interface.  That doesn't help anyone understand your API or use it easily.  The initializer or property object model is much more standard, and self describing in normal OO.

Comment: Object initializers don't allow for immutable object creation which are useful for certain things.

Answer (score 1):

No and yes. The basics are a good interface or interfaces for the types that you want to behave fluently. Libraries with extension methods can extend this behavior and return the interface. Extension methods give others the possibility to extend your fluent API with more methods.

A good fluent design can be hard and takes a rather long trial and error period to totally finetune the basic building blocks. Just a fluent API for configuration or setup is not that hard.

Learning building a fluent API does one by looking at existing APIs. Compare the FluentNHibernate with the fluent .NET APIs or the ICriteria fluent interfaces. Many configuration APIs are also designed "fluently".

Answer (score 1):

With a fluent API:

```
myCar.SetColor(Color.Blue).SetName("Aston Martin");
```

Check out this video http://www.viddler.com/explore/dcazzulino/videos/8/

Answer (score 1):

Writting a fluent API it's complicated, that's why I've written [Diezel](http://code.google.com/p/diezel/) that is a Fluent API generator for Java. It generates the API with interfaces (or course) to:

1. control the calling flow
2. catch generic types (like guice one)

It generates also implementations.

It's a maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on the behaviour you want to achieve for your fluent API. For a stepwise initialization the easiest way is, in my opinion, to create a builder class that implements different interfaces used for the different steps. E.g. if you have a class `Student` with the properties `Name`, `DateOfBirth` and `Semester` the implementation of the builder could look like so:

```cs
public class CreateStudent : CreateStudent.IBornOn, CreateStudent.IInSemester
{
    private readonly Student student;

    private CreateStudent()
    {
        student = new Student();
    }

    public static IBornOn WithName(string name)
    {
        CreateStudent createStudent = new CreateStudent();
        createStudent.student.Name = name;
        return createStudent;
    }

    public IInSemester BornOn(DateOnly dateOfBirth)
    {
        student.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        return this;
    }

    public Student InSemester(int semester)
    {
        student.Semester = semester;
        return student;
    }

    public interface IBornOn
    {
        IInSemester BornOn(DateOnly dateOfBirth);
    }

    public interface IInSemester
    {
        Student InSemester(int semester);
    }
}
```

The builder can then be used as follows:

```cs
Student student = CreateStudent.WithName("Robert")
    .BornOn(new DateOnly(2002, 8, 3)).InSemester(2);
```

Admittedly, writing an API for more than three properties becomes tedious. For this reasons I have implemented a source generator that can do this work for you: [M31.FluentAPI](https://github.com/m31coding/M31.FluentAPI).