# How to call method().method() in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Method-Chaining in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c-sharp)
> [creating API that is fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622662/creating-api-that-is-fluent)

How can I do the below coding?

```
Class1 objClass1 = new Class1().Add(1).Add(2).Add(3)...
```

and so on..

How can I implement the `Add()` method to call infinite time that will reflect on same object?

Comment: Use `return this;` and your method must have return type `Class1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, if you want to use the same object after the call then you must return that object, which is referred with **this** in the method.

```
class Class1
{
    public Class1 Add(int num)
    {
        //TODO
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is a case of **method-chaining**.

Comment: Another name for this design style is a *fluent interface*.

Answer (score 5):

It is called *[chainable methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)*.

> Method chaining, also known as named parameter idiom, is a common
>   technique for invoking multiple method calls in object-oriented
>   programming languages. Each method returns an object (possibly the
>   current object itself), allowing the calls to be chained together in a
>   single statement.

Basicly, your method should return a current instance of your object.

```
public YourClass Add()
{
    return this;
}
```

For a clean understanding of method chaining, here is the code converted from Java include in wikipedia page. The the setters return "`this`" (the current `Person` object).

```
using System;

namespace ProgramConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            // Output: Hello, my name is Soner and I am 24 years old.
            person.setName("Soner").setAge(24).introduce();
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Person setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Person setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public void introduce() {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello, my name is " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation for a novice like me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the Object itself to chain such method calls like this

```
public Class1 Add(Object Whatever)
{
    // Do code here
    return this;
}
```