# Effects of returning a self reference from an instance method in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an interface called `IConvertableModel` and it helps me to convert some MVC models to/from DTO objects as shown below:

```
public class DisplayEditModel : IConvertableModel<Display>
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Display ToDto()
    {
        return new Display
        {   
            Description = Description,
            ObjectId = ObjectId,
        };
    }

    public void SetFromDto(Display dto)
    {
        Description = dto.Description;
        ObjectId = dto.ObjectId;
    }
}
```

But there is one problem with this approach and that is it doesn't allow me do this :

```
var dto = _dtoRepository.GetFirstDto();
return new DisplayEditModel().SetFromDto(dto);
```

Instead I should do the following:

```
var dto = _dtoRepository.GetFirstDto();
var model = new DisplayEditModel();
model.SetFromDto(dto);
return model;
```

and this is adding extra two lines of code and little bit complexity in the long run.

What I am thinking is to convert `SetFromDto` method to something like this:

```
public DisplayEditModel SetFromDto(Display dto)
{
   Description = dto.Description;
   ObjectId = dto.ObjectId;
   return this;
}
```

I think the benefit of this code is obvious but I also like to learn whether this harms code readability and leads to unexpected results for developers in the long run and if you think anything else, what would you recommend.

Note: Because of the interfaces reasons, I am not thinking to implement a constructor method.

Comment: It sounds like the ideal method for this would be a static factory or possibly a constructor, but I don't think either of those can be interface-enforced unfortunately.

Comment: @David, you are right, right and right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622662/creating-api-that-is-fluent

Comment: Isn't this the exact scenario that AutoMapper was invented for? Why roll your own?

Comment: @DanM: Because AutoMapper has an evil side of it. When you change something, it won't give you proper compile time error and will blow up at run-time. So I want to explicitly specify what to map and get a good old compile time exceptions.

Comment: @Tarik, true, but AutoMapper does enable *test-time* error reporting through the `AssertConfigurationIsValid` method: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation

Comment: @DanM: It is good to know but won't give me the confidence of explicit mapping. It gives me a better control and easier code read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts, to begin with:

1. Adding lines of code is not the same as adding complexity. Having three statements, where each does a simple operation, is not necessarily harder to maintain or understand than a single statement with three operations inside of it.
2. When a method that begins with `Set...`, programmers will automatically assume that some stateful values of the target object are going to be changed by this method. It is rare for `Set` methods to have a return value. Property setters in C# actually "return" the original value passed into them, so you can chain setters:

   ```
   int i = foo.A = 2;
   ```

   So the precedent is generally against returning "this" from a `set` method specifically.
3. Chaining in general is most useful/desired when you're expecting several operations to be performed, one after the other. For example, C# provides nice initialization syntax so you can "chain" a bunch of different property setters on the same object:

   ```
   var foo = new Foo { A = 1, B = 2 };
   ```

   You can see how chaining is fulfilling the need to perform similar, grouped, repetitive operations that typically get performed all together. That is not the problem that you are trying to solve.

If your main gripe is that you don't like having three lines of code, why not just use a helper whose name indicates what you're trying to do?

```
TModel MapToModel<TModel, TDto>(TDto dto, TModel model)
    where TModel : IConvertableModel<TDto>
{
    model.SetFromDto(dto);
    return model;
}

// usage:

var dto = _dtoRepository.GetFirstDto();
return MapToModel(dto, new DisplayEditModel());
```

... or even:

```
TModel CreateModel<TModel, TDto>(TDto dto)
    where TModel : IConvertableModel<TDto>, new()
{
    var model = new TModel();
    return MapToModel(dto, model);
}

// usage:

var dto = _dtoRepository.GetFirstDto();
return CreateModel<DisplayEditModel>(dto);
```

This is simple, readable, and feasible, whereas the approach you're suggesting would break the `IConvertableModel<Display>` interface:

```
public interface IConvertableModel<TDto>
{
    public TDto ToDto();
    public ??? SetFromDto(TDto dto);
}
```

What would `SetFromDto` return? You would have to define another generic type on `IConvertableModel`.

```
public interface IConvertableModel<TDto, TModel> {
    public TDto ToDto();
    public TModel SetFromDto(TDto dto);
}
```

But this wouldn't really indicate that the `SetFromDto` method is necessarily returning *itself*, because it allows for a class that is not a `TModel` to implement `IConvertableModel` to convert between two other types.

Now, you *could* go out of your way to push the generics even farther:

```
public interface IConvertableModel<TDto, TModel>
    where TModel : IConvertableModel<TDto, TModel>
{...}
```

But this still allows for some fudging, and the interface cannot guarantee that you are really returning "this" object. All in all, I'm not a big fan of that approach.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step and very detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having `DisplayEditModel` have a get/set *method* for a `Display` object to get/set the values, just use a *property* that doesn't actually have a separate backing store:

```
public Display Display
{
    get
    {
        return new Display
        {
            Description = Description,
            ObjectId = ObjectId,
        };
    }
    set
    {
        Description = value.Description;
        ObjectId = value.ObjectId;
    }
}
```

Now you can use an object initializer with this property when creating a model:

```
return new DisplayEditModel() { Display = dto };
```

Comment: This is a Model which is passed down to client side by MVC. So I don't want to introduce another property that will not mapped at all by MVC model binders.

Comment: @Tarik Why not?  You can choose not to bind all of the properties.

Comment: @Tarik The other option is to create a constructor that takes a `Display` object, in addition to a parameterless constructor.  If all of that is a problem then just create a factory method, as has been said, that creates an object and sets the `Display` and then returns it.

Comment: Because it brings another concern for the developers about what to map and what not to map. Anything in the Model class should be there for being mapped, at least this is what I believe because this is why we have model classes.

Comment: @Servy: ViewModels in MVC are often decorated with custom attributes to give hints to editor templates and such: the repetition of properties from the data or business layer objects can be necessary and intentional, in order to provide a place for these attributes to be attached to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very javascript way of approaching this problem, though it has it's benefits. In the context of C#, it is a little bit strange though libraries such as LINQ do this to allow chaining together function calls.

My only worry about this, is that this has to be a class that does this consistently. Implementing a chaining function return pattern is not really a convenience as much as it is a design choice. The rule to follow in this case, would be to return `this` every time you mutate the object.

Chaining also may not be worth it performance wise. Something that can be done by wrapping all those operations into a single function is much faster. For instance:

```
   MyVector.setX(1).SetY(1).SetZ(1).SetW(0)
```

is a lot slower than simply

```
   MyVector.set(1, 1, 1, 0)
```

because now you are  now doing excessive stack operations to do something fairly simple. It only becomes worth it on very large operations that take up the bulk of the computing time and **make sense** to chain together. For this reason, LINQ allows you to chain things together.

I wouldn't say that it necessary "harms" or is dangerous. We are in the world of a managed language, so we don't have direct access to that memory location (unlike C/C++). So I would just call it a design choice which can be fairly powerful in some cases and not so much in others.

Comment: Chaining generally makes sense when you have immutable objects.  Returning an entirely new object, and then doing something with that new object to create a new object makes sense, and there really isn't any good way of dealing with immutable objects *besides* that.  You can store the intermediate objects in variables, but what would be the point.  Chaining makes much less sense for mutable objects though.

Comment: Vectors are a great example of mutable data that *kind* of uses this approach. Because we are talking about algebraic operations, you want to get a new copy every time you do something, like for instance, get the normalized version without affecting the original. These are usually done return by copy (structs provide this behavior in C#). They still however, remain mutable objects. As I have mentioned before, collections (list, array) linq operations return `this` so you can chain the operations together.

Comment: "a very javascript way..." It's probably more of a "very jQuery way." Javascript doesn't inherently give you more or less reason to chain, but jQuery leveraged chaining to make it easy to perform series of actions on a bunch of DOM elements. C# tends to chain when using LINQ operations where, as Servy points out, each operation yields a new immutable object based on the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, chainable methods work fine but are not as common in C# as in some other languages. If the extra lines of code only happen in one place, I'd just leave it alone. If it's really bugging you or you do it a lot, then consider implementing a special constructor for it:

```
public void DisplayEditModel(Display dto)
{
    this.SetFrom(dto);
}
```

or a static factory method:

```
public static DisplayEditModel CreateFrom(Display dto)
{
    var model = new DisplayEditModel();
    model.SetFrom(dto);
    return model;
}
```

Either option has a clear intent, lets you create and return the object in a single line, and is idiomatic. It does require a few extra lines of code in `DisplayEditModel`, but I doubt it will be a serious problem.