# Making my class 'fluent'

Tags: c#, fluent

I discovered yesterday that I can *simulate* a fluent interface if I return the class instance from each method like this...

```
public class IsThisFluent
{
    public IsThisFluent Stuff()
    {
        //...
        return this;
    }

    public IsThisFluent OtherStuff()
    {
        // ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is this all there is to it?

I admit, I'm a bear of very little brain and I want to carry on this this but I thought it might be best to check with a grown up.

Am I missing something?

Is there a 'gotcha' that I haven't spotted with this pattern?

Comment: that's the way i do it all the time... have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640997/Fluent-interfaces-and-Method-Chaining-in-Csharp

Comment: It's fairly common to do this when you are working with immutable classes. There's a good video of Jon Skeet somewhere writing a Tetris console application with this pattern. Edit: here it is... https://vimeo.com/68331762

Comment: It kind of depends on how you intend to use it, Does stuff really need to return anything or do anything with the object afterwards? I'm not sure how much of a performance hit this would make to return objects just for the sake of it

Comment: Thx for that. The article doesn't highlight any potential problems; can I assume, then, that there aren't any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return this` is not *all* there is to fluent interfaces.
Chaining methods is a simplistic form of building a fluent API, but fluent APIs generally look like DSLs (domain specific languages) and are much, *much* harder to design.

Take Moq as an example:

```
new Mock<IInterface>()
    .Setup(x => x.Method())
    .CallBack<IInterface>(Console.WriteLine)
    .Returns(someValue);
```

- The `Setup` method, defined on the type `Mock<T>`, returns an instance of `ISetup<T, TResult>`.
- The `Callback` method, defined for `ICallback<TMock, TResult>` returns an instance of `IReturnsThrows<TMock,TResult>`. Note that `ISetup<T, TResult>` extends `IReturnsThrows<TMock,TResult>`.
- Finally, `Returns` is defined on `IReturns<TMock,TResult>` and returns `IReturnsResult<TMock>`. Also note that `IReturnsThrows<TMock,TResult>` extends `IReturnsResult<TMock>`.

All these little nuances are there to force you to call these methods in a particular order, and to forbid you from calling `Setup` twice in a row, for example. Or from calling `Returns` before you call `Setup`.

These details are very important to ensure a good user experience.

To read more on designing fluent interfaces, take a look at Martin Fowler's article on [FluentInterface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions) is another prime example of how complex the design might get - but also of how much more readable the outcome is.

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty much it.

Here's a really good article on it:
<del>http://rrpblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=33</del>

**EDIT**
The original site seems to have died, so here's [WayBackMachine to the rescue](https://web.archive.org/web/20160809050251/http://rrpblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=33)

I also really like this example from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795027/131809

```
public class Coffee
 {
    private bool _cream;

    public Coffee Make { get new Coffee(); }
    public Coffee WithCream()
    {
      _cream = true;
      return this;
    }
    public Coffee WithOuncesToServe(int ounces)
    {
      _ounces = ounces;
      return this;
    }
 }

var myMorningCoffee = Coffee.Make.WithCream().WithOuncesToServe(16);
```

Which reminds me, I need a coffee now.

Comment: Thanks for that. Whilst I see why the 'Set' property is there (from a code pov) I don't really understand _why_ it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's pretty much it.

The idea behind is that you can chain method calls together manipulating internal state as you go. Ultimately the main goal of a [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is readability, LINQ being a very good example of one.