# Method chaining in C#

Tags: c#

Say I have some code like this

```
var addResult = GetAddResult(num1, num2);

var transformedResult = TransformResult(addResult );

if(CheckValidity(transformedResult))
{
    SendResult(transformedResult); 
}
else
{
    LogError(transformedResult);
}
```

I am writing such code in many places. Basically it is a function calls where the return value of one is the input of another. Also there are flow changes depends on some conditional checks.

Is there a way to write this in a more readable way?

For example

`ExecuteFlow.GetAddResult(num1,num2).TransformResult.CheckValidity.IfTrue.SendResult.IfFalse.LogError`;

Apologies for this is more of a conceptual clarification. But I would like to know if such a technique is feasible.

Comment: That the second is "more readable" sure sounds subjective to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating API that is fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622662/creating-api-that-is-fluent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a C# extensions,

e.g.

```
GetAddResult(num1, num2).Handle();
```

where the extension would be:

```
public static void Handle(this AddResult addResult)
{
    var transformedResult = TransformResult(addResult);

    if(CheckValidity(transformedResult))
    {
        SendResult(transformedResult); 
    }
    else
    {
        LogError(transformedResult);
    }
}
```

OR a bit more verbose:

```
GetAddResult(num1, num2).ToTransformResult().HandleValidity();
```

with these extensions:

```
public static TransformResult ToTransformResult(this AddResult addResult)
{
    return TransformResult(addResult);
}

public static void HandleValidity(this TransformResult addResult)
{
    if(CheckValidity(transformedResult))
    {
        SendResult(transformedResult); 
    }
    else
    {
        LogError(transformedResult);
    }
}
```

Not sure if that would fullfil all your requirements.

Comment: I agree that we could improve readability by extension functions. However my question is more in terms of having some techique to chain the methods with conditionals

Comment: then pass an `Action`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this

```
//let's assume this is the type that GetAddResult method is returning.
public class MyAddResult { ... }

//let's say this is what method TransformResult is returning.
public class MyTransformResult { ... }

public static class MyFlow {
    public static MyTransformResult TransformResult(this MyAddResult src) {
        ....
    }

    public static void IfValid(this MyTransformResult src, Action<MyTransformResult> methodIfTrue, Action<MyTransformResult> methodIfFalse) {
        if( CheckValidity(src) )
          methodIfTrue(src);

        methodIfFalse(src);
    }
}

//In another place
public void SendResult(MyTransformResult m) { ... }

//In another place
public void LogError(MyTransformResult m) { ... }
```

The usage will be:

```
GetAddResult(num1, num2).TransformResult().IfValid(SendResult, LogError);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Result.OfAdding(1, 2)
    .Transform()
    .IfValid(thenInvokeThis: () => Debug.Print("Valid"),
        elseInvokeThis: () => Debug.Print("Invalid"));
```

A bit of a twist on Dabbas's solution - the IsValid works really nicely, but I felt the initial setup could be smoother.

Firstly declaring a common interface and a static factory.

```
interface IAddResult
{
    int AddendA { get; set; }
    int AddendB { get; set; }
    int Sum { get; }
}

static class Result
{
    public static IAddResult OfAdding(int a, int b)
    {
        // TODO: Return add result.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then adding chaining functionality via extensions.

```
static class AddResultExtensions
{
    public static IAddResult Transform(this IAddResult addResult)
    {
        // TODO: Transform add result.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static void IfValid(this IAddResult addResult, Action thenInvokeThis, 
        Action elseInvokeThis)
    {
        // TODO: Validate.
        bool isValid = true ? throw new NotImplementedException() 
            : false;

        if (isValid)
        {
            thenInvokeThis();
        }
        else
        {
            elseInvokeThis();
        }
    }
}
```