# How can I have multiple extension methods on my own class, like this?

Tags: c#, class, extension-methods

```
string "hello world".toLower().toUpper().replace("o", "x");
```

How do I make my own class be able to have extension methods like string in the example above?
Maybe not that usefull, but I just cant figure out how to do it

Comment: Those aren't actually extension methods - they're just methods that return a string, which enables you to chain them.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called Fluent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called **chained** methods that can be used for fluent APIs.

One normally creates them by returning the same type from all method calls.

See [Tips for writing fluent interfaces in C# 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224730/1583).

Comment: Ah, I see. I must test this. Thanks!